# How to properly switch scenes/change root node of scene in JavaFX without FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm learning javafx and I already got basics done so now I want to make a bit more complex project. I read many guides online on this topic but I can't find anywhere how to switch scenes or change root node when every class represent 1 scene.
To understand better here is simplified version of my project:
Let's say that I have 3 classes A, B and C:

```
public class A{
    private Stage stage;
    A(Stage stage){
         this.stage = stage;
    }
    public void showGui(){
        // This will make all elements, put them on scene and then set that scene to stage
    }
    public void callB(){
        B b = new B(Stage);
        b.showGui();
    }
} 
public class B{
    private Stage stage;
    B(Stage stage){
         this.stage = stage;
    }
    public void showGui(){
        // This will make all elements, put them on scene and then set that scene to stage
    }
    public void callC(){
        C c = new C(Stage);
        c.showGui();
    }
} 
public class C{
  // This is completely same as other two, it calls A so those 3 form some sort of circle.  
}
```

At start of program inside  **public void start(Stage primaryStage)** I make object of A and pass it primary stage then in each class I change it, and it works fine. But I have few questions about it:
Is this a proper way of doing it?
Is there any other way to do it while keeping classes or I should just do all inside main class?
Is it better to pass Scene and then change root nodes?

Sorry if I ask a bit too much, but I read a lot about it still couldn't find anything that can help me, so this is my last solution.

Comment: Per the rules, questions should avoid asking multiple direct questions at once. Also, if Sergey answered your question satisfactorily, you should mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few design improvements you may pursue here:

1. Your classes don't need to know at all about `Stage` and other classes, see [hiding concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) -- the less they know  the less complex is your program. Root node of a Scene would be enough. You can even override Node to avoid extra code.
2. Your classes looks very similar. You may want to introduce parent abstract class and delegate all switching logic to a single method (so you wouldn't need to change all classes if your logic changed)

See next example:

```
public class FxThreeNodes extends Application {

    private abstract class CycledView extends StackPane { // Choose whatever is most appropriate class
        CycledView(CycledView next) {
            this.next = next;

            createGUI();
        }

        abstract void createGUI();

        protected void callNext() {
            getScene().setRoot(next);
        }

        private CycledView next;
    }

    // Here you implement diffent GUIs for A, B and C
    private class A extends CycledView { 

        public A(CycledView next) {
            super(next);
        }

        void createGUI() {
            getChildren().add(new Button("I'm A") {
                @Override
                public void fire() {
                    callNext();
                }

            });
        }

    }

    private class B extends CycledView { 

        public B(CycledView next) {
            super(next);
        }

        void createGUI() {
            getChildren().add(new Button("This is B") {
                @Override
                public void fire() {
                    callNext();
                }

            });
        }

    }

    private class C extends CycledView { 

        public C(CycledView next) {
            super(next);
        }

        void createGUI() {
            getChildren().add(new Button("Greeting from C") {
                @Override
                public void fire() {
                    callNext();
                }

            });
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        CycledView c = new C(null);
        CycledView b = new B(c);
        CycledView a = new A(b);
        c.next = a;

        Scene scene = new Scene(a, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me out a lot.